# Should Material Design web applications use @import or @use?

Tags: mdc-components

Looking at the [Material Components Web documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-chips#using-chips), I see inter alia `@use "material/chips/styles"`

When I visit [app.scss – adopt-a-pup](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/adopt-a-pup?path=app.scss%3A1%3A0) I see `@import` statements such as `@import "@material/chips/mdc-chips";`

I understand that `@use` is the newer modular way. Which sass approach  should I use?

Could the glitch demos be out of date? Is there an example reference anywhere that makes use of both, say, `mdc-chips` and `mdc-select`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely should use `@use`. *adopt-a-pup* is very outdated. It references MDC 0.41.0, while current version is 13.0.0.

Unfortunately MDC examples are very scarce and documentation at *material.io* is outdated sometimes. I recommend using docs on their [github repo](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages), it is the most current.

Also some time ago I put together these two starter kits. They might be of some help in terms of examples how to use MDC:

1. [Material Design Layout Kit for Angular](https://github.com/keks-code/angular-material-layout-kit)
2. [Basic Material Starter Kit](https://github.com/keks-code/basic-material-starter-kit)

Comment: I have updated the [Adopt A Pup](https://glitch.com/~adopt-a-pup) reference app with [mdc-web-demos: basic material-design-web applications](https://github.com/GaryB432/mdc-web-demos)